# probability of a quadratic form being nonnegative at a random point

Tags: pr.probability, quadratic-forms

I am looking for good and explicit lower and upper bounds on the probability that $x^TGx\ge 0$, where $G$ is a symmetric matrix with zero trace and $x$ is a vector whose components are independent random variables uniformly distributed in either $[-1,1]$ or $\{-1,1\}$.

(What I really need are realistically general explicit sufficient conditions on $G\in R^{n\times n}$ for the probability to be $\ge p$ for some $p>0$ independent of the dimension $n$. Thus the bounds should be strong enough to deduce such conditions and to prove that the gap between sufficient and necessary is not too large.)

Comment: Are moment bounds sufficient? (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_moment_method)

Comment: Only if one can deduce from them good bounds on the probabilities.

Comment: Well, the quality of the bounds will depend on what your $G$ is. If you don't have a specific $G$ in mind, then it would depend on what your requirements for "good" are. Try it and let us know if it is sufficient.

Comment: My $G$'s are certain parametric matrices of arbitrary dimension. The trace of $G$ is zero; so the second-moment method gives no result.